# Understanding the return from memcmp

Tags: c, memcmp

I wrote a function to simulate `memcmp`, and during testing I realized there is something unusual about `memcmp`. The source code for the library function is supposed to be:

```
#include <ansidecl.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int
memcmp(const void *str1, const void *str2, size_t count)
{
  register const unsigned char *s1 = (const unsigned char *)str1;
  register const unsigned char *s2 = (const unsigned char *)str2;

  while (count-- > 0)
    {
      if (*s1++ != *s2++)
        return s1[-1] < s2[-1] ? -1 : 1;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

mine is

```
#include <stddef.h>

int ft_memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n)
{
    size_t  i;

    i = 0;
    if (n == 0)
        return (0);
    while(((char *)s1)[i] == ((char *)s2)[i])
    {
        if ((((char *)s1)[i] == '\0') || (i == (n - 1)))
        {
            return (0);
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (((char *)s1)[i] < ((char *)s2)[i])
        return (-1);
    else
        return (1);
}
```

the unexpected issue is that, depending on the count provided, the `memcmp` function starts returning not `1` or `-1`, but the actual difference from the chars, namely `s1[-1] - s2[-2]`

Anyone knows why or how this happens?

this is the test I ran that showed me the issue

```
int main() {
    char *test_strings1[] = { "fdjkDKDJFLDkjdfkjdf", "-456", "ALO marciano!!!", "xc42:", "     7894545989828547", "  +99", "abc123", "12abc", "" };

    char *test_strings2[] = { "fdjkDKDJFLDSkjdfkjdf", "-456", "ALO_ALO marciano!!!", "xc42", "   789454598982854752", "  +99", "abc123", "12abc", "" };

    for (int count = 0; count < 50; count++)
        for (int string = 0; string < 9; string++) {
            int ft = ft_memcmp(test_strings1[string], test_strings2[string], count);
            int lib = memcmp(test_strings1[string], test_strings2[string], count);
       
            if (ft != lib) {
                printf("******Wrong!!!  lib  %i  ft  %i  count = %i  string = %i*********\n", lib,  ft, count, string);
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

My GCC version is

```
gcc --version
Ubuntu clang version 12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.5
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

My system is Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, Intel® Core™ i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4, Mesa Intel® Iris(R) Plus Graphics 640 (Kaby Lake GT3e) (KBL GT3)

this is the output I get, which surprised me. On all the strings that have difference (index 2, 3 and 4) the behaviour of `memcmp` changes if count is greater than `7` (in this version of the output my custom function was returning the difference, not 1,-1 and 0)

```
Wrong!!!  lib  -1  ft  -63  count =  4  string =  2
Wrong!!!  lib  -1  ft  -23  count =  4  string =  4
Wrong!!!  lib  -1  ft  -63  count =  5  string =  2
Wrong!!!  lib  +1  ft  +58  count =  5  string =  3
Wrong!!!  lib  -1  ft  -23  count =  5  string =  4
Wrong!!!  lib  -1  ft  -63  count =  6  string =  2
Wrong!!!  lib  +1  ft  +58  count =  6  string =  3
Wrong!!!  lib  -1  ft  -23  count =  6  string =  4
Wrong!!!  lib  -1  ft  -63  count =  7  string =  2
Wrong!!!  lib  +1  ft  +58  count =  7  string =  3
Wrong!!!  lib  -1  ft  -23  count =  7  string =  4
```

Comment: who says that the values should be +/-1 or 0? That's not how that function is defined.

Comment: [`memcmp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/memcmp-wmemcmp?view=msvc-170) does not return -1, 0 , or 1. It returns < 0, 0, or > 0.

Comment: No, the manual does not say that is how the function is defined, I just happened to run into this behaviour, some with -1/1 and others values of count with the diference. so I googled the cource code, and posted it here.

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/memcmp.c

Comment: It is allowed to return -1, 0, or 1, because they are within the spec of < 0 , 0 or > 0. *The source code for the library function is supposed to be...* no, it isn't supposed  to be that, as the man page I linked says.

Comment: C23 clause 7.26.4.1 says *The `memcmp` function **returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero**, accordingly as the object pointed to by s1 is greater than, equal to, or less than the object pointed to by s2.*

Comment: Well for one you showed code the demo strates the problem, but did not show the output of that code.  Without seeing what you expect and what you get, the question is not at all clear.  Secondly, memcmp promises only to return a positive, negative or zero value.  Your test should check only that the results are either both zero or both have the same sign.  The magnitude is undefined.  However it is indeed helpful to have downvotes explained.  But you cannot assime if course that those commenting are those whose downvotes.

Comment: Why does your `ft_memcmp()` have an explicit check for nul bytes? That's not what `memcmp()` does.

Comment: memcmp is designed to work on buffers filled with arbitrary binary data not just \0 - terminated strings.  Binary data may have multiple 0s, you might be comparing \0\0\0 1  with \0\0\0 2.

Comment: This is also true for `strcmp()` and the user's comparator function supplied to `qsort()`.

Comment: Your version is mor akin to `strncmp()` than `memcmp()`. `\0` is a perfectly legitimate _memory_ value, and should not be used to terminate the compare `memcmp` does not do that so will produce _different_ results.  You should not be surprised.

Comment: Since the question is predicated on your complete misunderstanding of `memcmp` rather than any fault with it, and that your code is clearly not semantically equivalent, I see no useful purpose in attempting to answer this question.  The advantage of closing it for you will be to protect you from further downvotes.

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot for your input. I should add, and by this I mean no offense whatsoever, that you have been focussing a little to much on details on my code, and kind of forgot the question, which is why does memcmp change it's behaviour after count 7. I Understand that both behaviors are compliant with the standard, and also that the source code I found online cannot be the one with this kind of quirky behavior, but still I can't really understand why the function was written like this.

Comment: @FernandoLoula: Re “focussing a little to much on details on my code, and kind of forgot the question”: Sorry, but you botched the question. The `ft_memcmp` code in the question only returns −1, 0, or +1; it never returns −63 as you show. Maybe you mixed up which code provided which output and posted mismatched code and output. This and other errors interfere with people understanding what you are asking or making sense of your post. Now, your code does not return differences between bytes, but the `memcmp` in a standard library implementation might…

Comment: … So I would believe that in some version of your code, you tested the standard `memcmp`, and it produced −1, 0, or +1 for strings of some lengths and differences between bytes for others. And, if that is what you wanted to ask about, you should have posted a simple test program, just a `main` routine with `#include <string.h>`, `#include <stdio.h>`, and some code to show a few test cases. None of your code to implement alternate versions of `memcmp` would have been needed for that…

Comment: … If that were the observed behavior with an implementation of `memcmp`, I expect the explanation would be that for short strings, the implementation is using one set of code that compares a byte at a time for a few bytes, whereas for long strings, especially if they start at nicely aligned addresses, it is using some form of SIMD code, and those two pieces of code differ in how they return their results (which is within the specification of `memcmp` by the C standard).

Answer (score 3):

From the C Standard (7.24.4.1 The memcmp function)

> **Returns**
>
> 3 **The memcmp function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or
> less than zero,** accordingly as the object pointed to by s1 is
> greater than, equal to, or less than the object pointed to by s2.

Answer (score 3):

The C Standard (C2x) specifies this:

> **7.26.4 Comparison functions**
>
> The sign of a nonzero value returned by the comparison functions `memcmp`, `strcmp`, and `strncmp` is determined by the sign of the difference between the values of the first pair of characters (both interpreted as `unsigned char`) that differ in the objects being compared.
>
> [...]
>
> The `memcmp` function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero, accordingly as the object pointed to by `s1` is greater than, equal to, or less than the object pointed to by `s2`.

The posted code for `memcmp` is just a possible implementation. The C Standard does not specify the exact return value for blocks with different contents, just the sign of the return value.  Hence returning `s1[-1] - s2[-1]` is just as compliant as returning `s1[-1] < s2[-1] ? -1 : 1` or `1 - 2 * (s1[-1] < s2[-1])`

Note also that your implementation has problems:

- it makes no sense to test `((char *)s1)[i] == '\0')` as `memcmp` does not stop on any null terminator.
- comparing the byte values as `char` values is incorrect: the C Standard specifies that the comparison must be performed using the `unsigned char` values.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stddef.h>

int ft_memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n)
{
    size_t  i;

    i = 0;
    if (n == 0)
        return (0);

    while (((unsigned char *)s1)[i] == ((unsigned char *)s2)[i])
    {
        i++;
        if (i == n)
        {
            return (0);
        }
    }
    if (((unsigned char *)s1)[i] < ((unsigned char *)s2)[i])
        return (-1);
    else
        return (1);
}
```

The `main` function is incorrect:

- it must only check for zero values and that the signs of `ft` and `lib` match if both are non zero.
- the `count` passed to both functions should not exceed the size of the objects.  This explains why you get inconsistent results when `count` is greater than `7` for the identical strings: the contents of memory beyond the first 8 or so bytes or the identical strings differ. Reading the bytes beyond the end of the strings (ie: after the null terminator) has undefined behavior anyway.

Here is a modified version:

```
int main(void) {
    const char *test_strings1[] = {
        "fdjkDKDJFLDkjdfkjdf", "-456", "ALO marciano!!!", "xc42:",
        "     7894545989828547", "  +99", "abc123", "12abc", ""
    };
    const char *test_strings2[] = {
        "fdjkDKDJFLDSkjdfkjdf", "-456", "ALO_ALO marciano!!!", "xc42",
        "   789454598982854752", "  +99", "abc123", "12abc", ""
    };
    int test_count = sizeof(test_strings1) / sizeof(*test_strings1);

    for (int i = 0; i < test_count; i++) {
        size_t size1 = strlen(test_strings1[i]) + 1;
        size_t size2 = strlen(test_strings2[i]) + 1;
        for (size_t count = 0; count <= size1 && count <= size2; count++) {
            int ft = ft_memcmp(test_strings1[i], test_strings2[i], count);
            int lib = memcmp(test_strings1[i], test_strings2[i], count);
       
            if ((ft < 0 && lib >= 0) 
            ||  (ft == 0 && lib != 0)
            ||  (ft > 0 && lib <= 0)) {
                printf("*** Wrong!!!  lib  %i  ft  %i  count = %zu  string = %i ***\n",
                       lib, ft, count, i);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are wright abou the '\0' check, it was vestigial from an implementation of strncmp. But Ithink I found out what might be going on, the memcmp has in fact two diferent implementations, one with an 8 byte block (like casting the pointers as long long int) that is called when count is smaller than 7 (the number is not random, 8 elements), and another version that goes char by char, used when count is greater than 7.

Comment: Advanced C compilers can implement `memcmp` as an intrinsic function and generate efficient code using a single comparison with or without a mask, depending on the target architecture, the constant count value, the byte ordering or how the return value is used.  It is very common for callers of `memcmp` to only test for a zero return value so compilers that will inline the `memcmp` code may simplify or omit the actual computation if the result.

Comment: @FernandoLoula: Note that the `main` function had undefined behavior when `count` is greater than the size of one of the objects.

Comment: I know about the undefined behavior in that case, it is actually just about trying a comprehensive test, see how stuff breaks, and compare it to how other stuff breaks. In a way it is more about having fun while figuring things out. BTW, I just found another interesting thing, strncmp does not have the same switching.

Comment: @FernandoLoula: what do you mean by *`strncmp` does not have the same switching*?... The count argument passed to `strncmp` can certainly be larger than the string lengths as the comparison stops at the null terminators.

Comment: I mean that when strncmp finds a difference on the first 8 chars of the string it does not return 1, -1 or 0, it returns the subtraction of s2[point of difference] from s1[point of difference], I can´t post code or output in the comments because of number of characters, but maybe if you test it yourself you can see it too, depends on you compiler implementation.

Comment: @FernandoLoula The cmp functions return a number less than 0, equal to 0, or greater than 0. *What* that number is is irrelevant (aside from when it's 0 of course) and not something you should waste time on.

Comment: In the final `main()`, I'd expect `ft_memcmp(), memcmp()` to get tested with calls with  `count + 1`, not `count`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: good point. Answer amended

Comment: @FernandoLoula: the return value of `strcmp`, `memcmp` and `strncmp` can be anything as long as its sign reflects the comparison result. The implementation is free to use any method to produce the return value, it is possible that your compiler uses a different method depending on the argument values, constant or variable at compile time, or depending on the time of day or even totally random. Only the sign matters for non zero return values. You can use [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://www.godbolt.org/z/jfjG7GME9) to see what how different compilers handle specific cases.

Comment: OTOH, a test of `n == 0` is good too.  Hmmm.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: all values of `count` between `0` and the lesser of `size1` and `size2` (inclusively) are tested, including a null count which requires an explicit test in the OP's code.

Comment: @chqrlie Ah yes, I see that now.

Answer (score 0):

the original function (very simplified) is rather:

```
int mymemcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, const size_t n)
{
    const unsigned char *a = s1;
    const unsigned char *b = s2;
    int result = 0;

    for(size_t index = 0; index < n; index ++)
    {
        if(a[index] != b[index])
        {
            result = a[index] - b[index];
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I still don´t understand why, but that is not the original function, that describes better what you get from strncmp. memcmp, for some reason possibly related to optimization, runs one procedure for n < 8 (possibly casting as a long long int with a mask determined by n) and the procedure you described for n >= 8. The first procedure is the one that returns 1, -1 or 0.

Comment: `if(a[index] != b[index])` is extraneous.  `result = a[index] - b[index]; if (!result) return result;`  is more likely to use a hardware "branch on zero" instruction under optimization.

Comment: On select machines, `a[index] - b[index]` can return the wrong signed difference when `UCHAR_MAX >= INT_MAX`.   Think graphics processors where `char` is 32-bit.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I do not think that OP will have this problem. I never had in my 40y programming carrier.

Comment: @0___________, Agreed, yet it remains a supporting rational for preferring low cost `return ((unsigned char *)s1)[i] < ((unsigned char *)s2)[i] ? -1 : 1);` like code.